# IPC Queue msgsnd error

Tags: c, ipc

This is a simple program to send msg to queue but it gives "snd error" as the output.
the queue is created. I checked with ipcs -q.
What have i done wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct msg{
int mtype;
char mtext[1024];

}snd;
void main()
{
int id;
if(id=msgget(1234,IPC_CREAT|0666)<0)
{
    printf("ipc error");
}
else{
    snd.mtype=1;
    scanf("%[^\n]",snd.mtext);
    getchar();

    if(msgsnd(id,&snd,sizeof(snd.mtext),IPC_NOWAIT)<0){
            printf("snd error");
    }
    else {
        printf("msg snd");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: why are you scanf then getchar()? Look into using fgets?

Comment: but that should not be a problem i guess. I tried copy pasting and running the code at    http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/ipc-message-queue-implementation-in-c.html     this works properly. But my program does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What have i done wrong?

You check the return code of `msgsnd`, which is good, and this means, you're already ahead of many programmers. But you haven't read the whole manual of [`msgsnd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html), which states

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   On failure both functions return -1 with *errno* indicating the error,

where [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is the important part.

When you look further, there's also a section named ERRORS, which shows what might go wrong

> **ERRORS**
>          When msgsnd() fails, errno will be set to one among the following
>          values:
>
> ```
>   EACCES The calling process does not have write permission on the
>           message queue, and does not have the CAP_IPC_OWNER capability.  
>
>   EAGAIN The message can't be sent due to the msg_qbytes limit for the
>           queue and IPC_NOWAIT was specified in msgflg.
> ```
>
> ...

And still further down, you will find an example section

> **EXAMPLE**
>
> ```
>   The program below demonstrates the use of msgsnd() and msgrcv().
> ```
>
> ...

Where the usage of `msgsnd` shows an important idiom: when an error occurs and the specific error is reported in `errno`, this error may be printed by [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

```
if (msgsnd(qid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext),
           IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) {
    perror("msgsnd error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`perror` will show a message detailing what went wrong with the call to `msgsnd`. This can also be used with any other system call.

---

According to the manual "Invalid argument" (`EINVAL`) means one of

> EINVAL msqid was invalid, or msgsz was less than 0.
>   EINVAL (since Linux 3.14) msgflg specified MSG_COPY, but not IPC_NOWAIT.
>   EINVAL (since Linux 3.14) msgflg specified both MSG_COPY and MSG_EXCEPT.

Since you don't specify `MSG_COPY`, the error must be the first one.

- `msgsz` is definitely greater than 0
- So it must be an invalid msqid!

When you look at

```
if(id = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT | 0666) < 0)
```

you see the missing parentheses around `(id = msgget(...))`. Most likely `msgget` returns a value > 0, so `msgget(...) < 0` is false, id will become 0 (false), and the else branch is taken.

As a consequence, calling `msgsnd(0, ...)` is most likely the culprit and source of the error.

---

To fix this, be explicit

```
id = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (id < 0) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

or put at least parentheses around the assignment

```
if ((id = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
```

Comment: it says "invalid argument" . i searched for the solution but i do not have that kind of problem. Like my size is good...message i enterd is less than 1024. my mtype = 1 which is positive. And the sizeof(snd.mtext) is also not wrong.  Now what is the problem?

Comment: The problem that i am facing is when i try to run a similar program it works. but this program is not working. This program works fine when i run it http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/ipc-message-queue-implementation-in-c.html  and another program which i wrote myself is also working. Why not this one?